# Count the number of times that new line/lines Appear

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there any way I could read the number of times that new lines appear in return value? I tried `regexp_count()` but `\n` only counts the number of times that `n` appear in return values.

```
SELECT REGEXP_COUNT(DATA, '\n', 1, 'i') , _DATA FROM DATA_TABLE ;
```

Sample below should return `3`.

```
ABCSLLA
AAANN
SDSDS
```

Comment: That's a result set, right? Rows in a result set are not terminated by a new line. You should explain what problem you're trying to solve - why you need this count - and then we may be able to help you.

Comment: If you view value in SQL Developer new line will appear..

Answer (score 1):

Flip `REGEXP_COUNT` into multi-line mode then you can use `$` to count *end-of-line* rather than *end-of-string*. Detailed in [Table 8.2 for multiline and 8.3 for $ here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_regexp.htm#ADFNS231). Example

```
SELECT REGEXP_COUNT(DATA, '$', 1, 'm') , _DATA FROM DATA_TABLE;
```

One interesting side effect it that this will return 3 with your data if the last line is OR is not terminated by a newline character.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the values are all in one row, you can try `SELECT REGEXP_COUNT(DATA, '\A', 1, 'i') , _DATA FROM DATA_TABLE ;`

[REF:https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_count.php](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_count.php)

Comment: it only matches the beginning of a string or matches at the end of a string before a newline character this will always return 1

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
SELECT REGEXP_COUNT(DATA, CHR(10), 1, 'i') , _DATA FROM DATA_TABLE;
```

If you want to search for carriage returns, that would be CHR(13).
I've created a demo [here](http://rextester.com/NIV25514)

Answer (score 0):

The below query should work for you.

```
SELECT length(regexp_replace(DATA, '[^'||chr(10)||']', '')) + 1 FROM DATA_TABLE;
```

Comment: I think this won't work. I attached sample result above.

Comment: Think or doesn't work? I have a table `DATA_TABLE` with column `DATA` and it has three lines of the sample given in the question. The query given in my answer returns 3.